# Signalr - websocket successfully connected but client events only called with long pooling

Tags: websocket, signalr, real-time, long-polling

I'm using windows server 2012 and activated websockets on it.
When signalr use websockets, the connection is successfully started but no event in client side are called, only if I force signalr to connect with long polling....

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you call the server from the client? Did you turn on logging/tracing to see what's going on?

Comment: Yes I can... No I will try... does it's can be because port ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a proxy? Try using https instead of http.

Comment: That what I receive : "signalr failed to execute. Error: Response is not available in this context." Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you possibly share more information, full logging results the full trace results, how your client is setup and how you are initialising SignalR server side, without more information it will be pretty hard to help find the cause of your problems. Are you by any chance trying to do anything authentication related in the SignalR hub?