# Signalr - Connection started but client events not called with websockets

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm consuming a service using signalr 2.2. All was working well using long polling. However since my service started to use websockets the hub events are inconsistent triggered. The connection is stablished but sometimes the clients events works, sometimes aren't triggered. I tried several approaches in order to get the code working as was using long polling but without success.

Ps1. I'm setup the client events before $.connection.hub.start
Ps2. Sorry, english is not my first language
PS3. I saw some questions here, but I can't find any solution...

- [Signalr - websocket successfully connected but client events only called with long pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870898/signalr-websocket-successfully-connected-but-client-events-only-called-with-lo)
- [WebSocket Connection Established, but Client Can't Receive Messages from Others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174333/websocket-connection-established-but-client-cant-receive-messages-from-others)

PS4. I asked a ticket at github, so I'd glad if you can take a look https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3502

Comment: He's not. SignalR falls back to long polling. His problem is the websocket transport is failing to call client events while longPolling transport is calling them.

Comment: Do you know how I can improve this? As is, seems not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using e.g. jQuery SignalR 1.1.3 works fine and events from the hubs are pushed to the clients. For this I use a jQuery component called Kendo Grid from Telerik. 
To implement this all I use an Angular front end for handling all actions to the hub (which is hosted in an ASP.NET WebAPI)

Only issue I am getting is that when changing it to //ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.min.js that data still is returned by the methods but client events aren't processed anymore by the clients.

Thus, my advise for you would be to temporarily downgrade to 1.1.3 to test if it then works.